# Pyinstaller with Kivy: ImportError: No module named garden.graph

Tags: python, kivy, exe, pyinstaller, importerror

I have a problem creating an .exe file with PyInstaller from my Kivy App.

I use Garden Graph to display some plots in my app.

I develop under Linux but I have to deploy my app for Windows.

I did install all needed dependencies under Win and I can execute my app with no problems, indeed.

When I try to compile it in order to create an executable file it succeeds but when I launch my .exe I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named garden.graph
Failed to execute script myapp
```

I tried --onefile, --onefolder, tried adding module with hiddenimports, added module path... with no luck.

Any ideas?